# Trouble compiling gloox library project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, xmpp, gloox

I'm having trouble compiling gloox in VS 2010. I'm getting followinng error report:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: gloox-1.0, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
 Creating library C:\Install\gloox-1.0.13\Release\gloox-1.0.lib and object     C:\Install\gloox-1.0.13\Release\gloox-1.0.exp
1>adhoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual   class gloox::IOData * __thiscall gloox::IOData::clone(void)const " (?clone@IOData@gloox@@UBEPAV12@XZ)
1>adhoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class gloox::Tag * __thiscall gloox::IOData::tag(void)const " (?tag@IOData@gloox@@UBEPAVTag@2@XZ)
1>adhoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall gloox::IOData::~IOData(void)" (??1IOData@gloox@@UAE@XZ)
1>adhoc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall gloox::IOData::IOData(class gloox::Tag const *)" (??0IOData@gloox@@QAE@PBVTag@1@@Z)
1>C:\Install\gloox-1.0.13\Release\gloox-1.0.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Could someone help me, what am I missing here? I'm new to C++ programming and new VS user so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Right click project > add > Existing File.
Then Add iodata.cpp and iodata.h.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I figured it out eventually :)